# multiple audio to netStream?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

hi I am working on a video conferance project
there will be a lecturer and an interpreter.
interpreter will write the translated text simultaneously.
what I am trying to is add vocal translation but I also want to keep the original audio 
is it possible to attach multiple audio to netStream or do I have to create another netStream for 2nd audio??
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Only one connection can exist per NetStream object.  You'd have to create a second NetStream to pull in the second feed.

That said, if your stream already has multiple audio channels, you may be able to play only the one desired using [SoundTransform](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundTransform.html). In this scenario, english would be in the left channel and language X would be in the right channel.  If you wanted only language X, then you'd set `leftToLeft` and `leftToRight` to 0, and visa-versa for `rightToLeft` and `rightToRight`